# Elliptic Curves and Discriminants

Tags: elliptic-curves, discriminant

So I am given a curve, $E$, with equation:
$$ f(x,y) = y^2 - x^3 - ax - b = 0 $$
and I have to prove that if the discriminant $\Delta = 4a^3 + 27b^2 = 0$ then E is singular.

Because I have been given this information as an assumption throughout the year, I am struggling to understand a way to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** You want to show the point at infinity is never singular (just homogenize and then take the $z$-partial). Otherwise, your curve will have a singular point if and only if $x^3+Ax+B$ has a repeated root if and only if the discriminant is $0$. Compute the discriminant of your polynomial in terms of $A,B$, what do you get?

Comment: Ok I understand your hint, but this would have to require a Weierstrass equation and I am not being taught that in my Cryptography module.

Comment: @lewisjiles I would have to know a lot more about what you do/do not know from course material. However it is worth noting that if your class intends to black-box much of elliptic curves (which is perfectly reasonable) then it may not be possible (or at least simple) to prove this statement. If you're not deeply interested, Silverman-Tate or Silverman have these proofs, as does any standard elliptic curve book.

Comment: Went through the question today and finally got the answer! Thank you for your help! Just needed more time to understand.